# Extract contents of multiple directories via 7zip (without creating subfolders)

Tags: windows, zip, 7-zip

I have a large directory of `zip` files, each containing a single file. I would like to extract all the zip files automatically, into one directory.

7-zip has a feature to extract multiple zips into the same directory. However, it creates a sub-directory for each original zip. Here is what the before and after look like:

### Before:

```
- before
  - a.zip
    - a.txt
  - b.zip
    - b.txt
  - c.zip
    - c.txt
  - d.zip
    - d.txt
```

### After:

```
- after
  - a
    - a.txt
  - b
    - b.txt
  - c
    - c.txt
  - d
    - d.txt
```

However, my desired output is this:

```
- after
  - a.txt
  - b.txt
  - c.txt
  - d.txt
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What was the command line you used for the first result? That's exactly what I'm trying to do and can't!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this on the command line with the "e" switch.

```
7za e archive.zip -o\\path\to\target
```

The -o switch is optional, and lets you specify a target directory for unpacking.  Don't put a space between the -o and the path.  If you don't specify it, the current directory will be used.

Just be careful that your archive doesn't have files with the same name in different folders.

Answer (score 2):

If you select all the zip files in Explorer and right-click, you should find an option `Extract Here` under the `7-Zip` menu. This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a batch file for this task.  Something like:

```
::Path where zip files are stored
SET SOURCEPATH=C:\zips\before

::Target Path where extracted files will be stored
SET TARGETPATH=C:\zips\after

::path to 7-zip
SET Z=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

::Extract each file in source folder into target
FOR %%f in (%SOURCEPATH%\*.zip) do "%Z%" e %%f -o%TARGETPATH%
```

This batch file will unzip all files in the "Before" folder with the "zip" extension into the "After" folder.   You must modify the source, target, and 7zip paths.